# Cannot do Alpha Animation with LinearLayout on Android

Tags: android, animation, android-linearlayout

So I was trying to make a ActionButton like Trello have (click on a button, a black overlay apears, and other buttons appear on the screen).

But I had one weird problem: I cannot make the alpha animation work.

I tryed in two ways:

```
private void initializeComponent(final Context ctx, final AttributeSet attrs) {
    blackOverlay.setAlpha(0.0f);
    blackOverlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    blackOverlay.setClickable(true);

    actionButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final boolean closed = blackOverlay.getAlpha() == 0.0f;
            blackOverlay.animate().alpha(closed ? 1f : 0f).setDuration(500).setListener(null);
    });
}
```

So in this way, the view `blackOverlay` is **always** visible and the animation should work. But it doesn't. Clicking the button does not make any difference on alpha. The only change is that toggling the button makes the non-overlay content work/stop work (as it should since blackOverlay is clickable).

So I tryed another approach: not setting the alpha to 0.0f so the overlay will start visible to the user. Basically commenting the first line of initializeComponent method.

```
private void initializeComponent(final Context ctx, final AttributeSet attrs) {
    //blackOverlay.setAlpha(0.0f);
    blackOverlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    blackOverlay.setClickable(true);

    actionButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final boolean closed = blackOverlay.getAlpha() == 0.0f;
            blackOverlay.animate().alpha(closed ? 1f : 0f).setDuration(500).setListener(null);
        }
    });
}
```

In this way, the button only **toggles** the alpha, it doesn't animate it.

Any ideas? I've already tryed a lot of solutions here on StackOverflow.

Thanks!

This is my xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/blackoverlay"
        android:background="@color/black_overlay">

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/action_button"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:src="@drawable/plus"
        android:layout_margin="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This code seems to work okay. Please create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and validate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I did a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as karaokyo said but the fun thing was: It worked on MCVE.

So I started looking at my entire code and I found that I had a `setOnClickListener` for a Button that had the same name as `action_button`. So I just changed the IDs to not be the same and everything is working now.

It seens it was my bad, I'm stupid lol

**So for anyone that is reading this**: Try to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) from scratch (new project even) and see if it works. It maybe be something else non-related interfering in your code.